# NoSQL keyword search in huge table

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, bigtable, nosql

I'm curios how can a NoSQL solution support keyword search in a very very big table distributed accross multiple servers?

By keyword search I mean a DB like the one Google has, with huge amount of documents, and with the ability to answer such question like find "hotels in New York" very fast indeed.

I see very simple solution to support OR operation in NoMysql solution (for example, queries like: "A or B or C") - just to use another very big distributed table that will hold an inverted index from any word to the document it is found in. In such case, given "A or B or C", we can just go directly to "A" or "B" or "C" entries in the index table and collect all the documents-ids. Then, once we have the ids to to fetch the documents themselfes.

But how to design a DB that will support efficient AND operations (for example, if I need to search for "A and B and C")?

Comment: for a "very very big table distributed accross multiple servers" using mongodb you would want to look at sharding; see document here: http://www.mongodb.org/download/attachments/2097354/how+queries+work+with+sharding.pdf in conjunction with the mongodb docs on efficient schema design: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you to take a look at [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: Seems they already solved similar problem, but it's interesting to know what is the design that supports efficient AND operations?